# Assign task from contact in public folder; worked in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Outlook 2010 with Exchange Server. We have a contacts folder for customers in Public Folders\All Public Folders. The user opens the contact (in public folder) then uses the "Assign Tasks" button on the contact form Communicate group to create a task which saves in the user's own task folder (not public folder). Works great in versions 2007 or 2003 and has a link to the contact in the public folder.

When we try to do this in Outlook 2010, we get the error message "You cannot assign a task from a public folder". I'm a little confused about what changed from the older versions. I'm not trying to save the task in the public folder. It should be saving in the personal task folder. So why the problem?

Also if I start a task first (personal folder) and only then create a link to the customer contact (public folder) then it works fine in all versions. So what I want to do is clearly possible.

So I guess I'm wondering if something is set wrong somewhere to enable this.

Comment: I'm a little bit unclear on your question. You have a global address book that you use to assign personal tasks to yourself with?

Comment: It's not a global address book, but a public folder on Exchange Server that contains customer contacts. But regardless of where the contact is stored you should be able to click the Assign Task button and get a new task that has a link to the relevant contact.